# PayPal - Invalid caller, requires client_id & secret

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to make a request to Paypal to get a new access token, but when trying a simple curl call, it's returning with this error -

"Invalid_request - Invalid caller, requires client_id & secret"

Not quite sure what's wrong with this. The client id and secret are correct and are included.

Here is what I've tried -

```
                $clientId = "XXX";
                $secret = "XXX";
                $url = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token";
                $method = 'POST';
                $postvals = sprintf("client_id=%s&client_secret=%s&grant_type=%s&refresh_token=%s",
                            $clientId,
                            $secret,
                            'refresh_token',
                            $refreshToken);


                $ch = curl_init($url);

                 if ($method == 'POST'){
                     $options = array(
                        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
                        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postvals,
                    );
                    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
                 } 

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 1); 
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $clientId.":".$secret); 
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true); 
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10); 
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                  "Accept: application/json",
                  "Accept-Language: en_US",
                  "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                  'Authorization: Bearer '.$old_accessToken,
                  "Host: www.paypal.com",
                  "Connection: close"
                 )
                );

                $result = curl_exec($ch);

                // Get Request and Response Headers
                $requestHeaders = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
                $responseHeaderSize = strlen($result) - curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD);
                $responseHeaders = substr($result, 0, $responseHeaderSize);

                //only use body and not header, otherwise return is NULL
                $result = substr($result, $responseHeaderSize);

                if(!$result || empty($result)){
                    echo 'Curl error or response is empty: ' . curl_error($ch);
                    curl_close($ch);
                } else {
                    curl_close($ch);
                    $response =json_decode($result);
                    var_dump($response);
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked instead -

```
    $clientId = "XXXX";
    $clientSecret = "XXXX";
    $url = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token";
    $method = 'POST';
    $postdata = sprintf("client_id=%s&client_secret=%s&grant_type=%s&refresh_token=%s",
                                $clientId,
                                $secret,
                                'refresh_token',
                                $refreshToken);

   $curl = curl_init($url); 
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $clientId . ":" . $clientSecret);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
   #    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
   $response = curl_exec( $curl );
            if (empty($response)) {
                // some kind of an error happened
                die(curl_error($curl));
                curl_close($curl); // close cURL handler
            } else {
                $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
                echo "Time took: " . $info['total_time']*1000 . "ms\n";
                curl_close($curl); // close cURL handler
                if($info['http_code'] != 200 && $info['http_code'] != 201    ) {
                    echo "Received error: " . $info['http_code']. "\n";
                    echo "Raw response:".$response."\n";
                    die();
                }
            }
   // Convert the result from JSON format to a PHP array 
   $jsonResponse = json_decode( $response );
```